# Git Merge subdirectory to branch to root directory of master

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch that has the content of the master branch as a subdirectory. Now I made some changes to this subdirectory. Ideally I want to be able to merge these changes back into the master branch.

Branch layout:

```
index.html
subdirectory
  > a.txt
  > b.txt
```

Master layout

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

How would I go about doing this? Is it even a good approach? In SVN I avoided merging subdirectories back into the trunk. But this is a somewhat different use case, the layout of both, the branch and master, will never change.

Comment: How did your branch get into that state in the first place? The root of your feature branch should always be the root of your master branch.

Comment: I know. I need this structure for my Github project page. The master branch reflects the current development branch of a small web application. 

Github supports delivery of html pages (and css,...) if they exist in a branch called gh-pages. The index.html is the welcome page, where you find general infos about the project, whereas the subdirectoy contains the iphone webapplication.

Comment: @Jimmy: just for information, the OP oschrenk just answered your question about "How did your branch get into that state in the first place".

Comment: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply (section "Comment @username Notifications"): if your comment doesn't begin with @Jimmy, he won't notice your answer (unless he actually revisit this question)

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the heads up (and for notifying Jimmy Cuadra). First time arround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

- making a branch from your current branch (`git branch to_be_merge_to_master`)
- moving back your file to the correct structure (`git mv ...`)
- merging that second branch to master

Comment: @VonC  while this is a solution, it would be cool if you could  directly merge a sub-directory of a given branch. i have the same need as the author or this question, due to the way gh-pages work.

Comment: @alex then the approach in https://gist.github.com/833223 ("Setup GitHub Pages "gh-pages" branch and "master" branch as subfolders of a parent project folder ("grandmaster")."), initially presented in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4993758/6309 can be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

make use of git submodules

Comment: This seems like the way to go in the long run. In case of the Github project page I would need a separate project to display the application(s). Maybe I move them to my user page.