# git branch: gh-pages

Tags: git, git-branch, github-pages

I have a repo on GitHub. Recently I have discovered GitHub's pages and I want to use them.
I would like to create this new branch and then, when I need to, either commit on `master` branch or on `gh-pages` branch.

How can I do this? Do I have to create another folder inside my repo?

Comment: `origin` isn't a branch, it's a remote. You mean `master`.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I'll edit.

Comment: See [my related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29616287/946850) and a [writeup](http://krlmlr.github.io/git-subbranch) for a solution that consists of creating a clone in a subdirectoy of the working copy.

Comment: You [no longer need a gh-pages branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750520/git-branch-gh-pages/39024454#39024454).

Comment: @DanDascalescu why not post an own answer in addition to all your comments here. What is your link for, it links to the question here?

Comment: @Timo: I see why you're confused. I had actually posted an answer here, and the link is to *that answer* (note the anchor id after the `#`), but @Martijn Pieters [deleted it](https://imgur.com/a/cPlAB72), and [SE has been repeatedly refusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340714/deletion-notification) to implement any notifications about deleted answers, so I had no idea it was deleted. Anyway, [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45220305/1269037) still points to the simpler method of just telling GitHub which folder to serve the pages from; no special branch needed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You might find this tutorial useful:

[Setup GitHub Pages "gh-pages" branch and "master" branch as subfolders of a parent project folder ("grandmaster")](https://gist.github.com/833223).

To me this approach seems simpler then doing a `git checkout gh-pages` each time you want to edit your gh-pages content. Let me know what you think ^_^

**Edit:** I updated the tutorial link - thanks @Cawas. The old tutorial (not recommended) was https://gist.github.com/825950

Comment: @rubik it's actually better to use the second suggestion from the same author: https://gist.github.com/833223

Comment: GitHub has just enabled using [any branch and directory as the source for the docs](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing). You no longer have to use `gh-pages`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It's not true. You can only use the master branch, or the master branch's docs folder, or gh-pages. Not "any" branch. Those are the only 3 possibilities as of April 2020.

Answer (score 42):

More recent versions of git have an alternative to the `git symbolic-ref` method that Chandru explained. This avoids having to use the lower level commands.

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git rm -rf .
```

Comment: I don't get this. How is this anything related to `symbolic-ref`?

Comment: @Cawas Previously the only way to do this was to use `git symbolic-ref` like in Chandru's answer. Now `git checkout --orphan` is the proper way.

Comment: but, @arrow, when I see the docs about both they don't seem to do the same thing at all! about `symbolic-ref` it says "*symbolic links are now deprecated and symbolic refs are used by default*" while about `orphan` it says "*This can be useful when you want to publish the tree from a commit without exposing its full history*". To me that's the opposite. You're creating a completely separated branch instead of making one the mirror of the other!

Comment: @Cawas `git symbolic-ref` is a plumbing command used every time a ref is updated to point to a different commit. This includes every time `git checkout` is used. It is not ment to be called manually which is why `git checkout --orphan` was added.

Comment: So, `orphan` actually adopts the orphan rather than creates one, is that it? and it does same thing than `symbolic-ref`, except we have to call it? This would probably be much easier explained through a good example.

Comment: @Cawas `--orphan` takes the start-point (HEAD if not specified) and creates a new branch with no history from that point. The additional `git rm -rf .` in my answer is to remove the previous content for when you want the branch to start with no content at all. When you run `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages` when gh-pages does not exist yet, it puts the repo in a state similar to right after `git init` before the first commit is made, so the following commit will not have a parent. `--orphan` was added for that very specific use case of `symbolic-ref`, but not to replace other uses.

Comment: Oh ok! I see now what you meant. Thanks for the explicit explanation! So, if I got this right, the *symbolic link* created by `symbolic-ref` is actually removed by one of the 2 subsequent commands.

Comment: @Cawas No there is no *symbolic link* involved, that is the old way. Go into a repository and try `cat .git/HEAD` and `cat .git/refs/heads/master`. Those files are created by `git symbolic-ref`. The first normally just references another (except when you have a detached HEAD) while the other will point to a specific commit SHA1.

Comment: It's not the file system's *symbolic link* per say, but it behaves like it, inside git. And it is a **link** nevertheless. Same concept, isn't it not? I see how my comment was confusing, and cool thing analyzing the .git/ files. Never did it before! :)

Comment: You also might want to `git clean -df`, because there may be files in the working-directory that weren't currently tracked (i.e. `.gitignore`'d files), that were not removed by `git rm` for that reason, but will *now* be attended to due to the removal of a possible `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 13):

On your local clone do,

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
rm .git/index 
git clean -fdx
```

Then, `git checkout gh-pages` and write your pages. `git push origin gh-pages` when you're ready to publish the pages.

Comment: Yes, but where do I put my pages? How does git know what pages to put in gh-pages?

Comment: `git checkout gh-pages` means you've switched to the branch named 'gh-pages'. Any change you commit to this branch is picked up by github to build your github pages. To switch back to the 'master' branch (presumably your source code), do `git checkout master`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847609/create-a-git-symbolic-ref-in-remote-repository

Comment: GitHub has just enabled using [any branch and directory as the source for the docs](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing). You no longer have to use `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 4):

There's yet another solution to your problem: Forget about `gh-pages` and branching; Put your static files that are supposed to be served inside `/docs` directory and then go to your project settings and tell github to serve `/docs` content.

For more information take a look at [this](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#publishing-your-github-pages-site-from-a-docs-folder-on-your-master-branch)

Comment: I generate javascript from Elm code and I don't want to have javascript polute my repository code. Right now this is my script for deploying https://github.com/rofrol/closeyoureyesnow/blob/master/build_and_deploy.sh

Answer (score 2):

Publish a static site like this:

```
git subtree push --prefix www origin gh-pages
```

Where `www` is the doc root directory in which your static files are.
Your static site is now live at:
`https://[user_name].github.io/[repo_name]/`

Comment: does not work for me. I get ```reset gh-pages branch to master ...\nfatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/gh-pages of non-bare repository\nfatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly```. I use this ```git push origin `git subtree split --prefix build`:$DEPLOY --force``` https://github.com/rofrol/closeyoureyesnow/blob/master/build_and_deploy.sh

Answer (score 1):

> **Creating Project Pages manually**
>
> Adding a new set of Pages for a project manually is a straightforward
> process if you're used to using command-line git.

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually

Answer (score 1):

Are your gh-pages and master branch having EXACTLY the same folder structure? If this is the case why do you even want to have two branches? just maintain one gh-pages branch! but if for whatever reason you want to have both branches that are constantly synced then your best bet is to use `git rebase`. See here: 
http://lea.verou.me/2011/10/easily-keep-gh-pages-in-sync-with-master/

You can also cherry pick only the files you need from master and push them onto gh-pages using a special use case of `git checkout`. See here: 
http://oli.jp/2011/github-pages-workflow/#gh-pages-workflow 
http://nicolasgallagher.com/git-checkout-specific-files-from-another-branch/

Having had to tackle with the same problem I've come to find that gh-pages will usually end up having a different code base than master. In other words, gh-pages should only include the content of the dist/build/publish folder of your project whereas master will include your config files, unminified scripts and styles etc.

My suggestion would be to create gh-pages as an `--orphan` branch and only include the publication-ready material in it. You would have to clone from your master in a different local directory, use `git checkout --orphan gh-pages` to create gh-pages and then delete all the unnecessary files using `git rm -rf .`. From there you can go on and push to gh-pages after having added your publish-only files.
Refer to Github docs for more info: 
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/

Good luck

Comment: GitHub has just enabled using [any branch and directory as the source for the docs](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing). You no longer have to use `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is to switch branches: `git checkout master` if you want to work on master and `git checkout gh-pages` if you want to work on `gh-pages`.

Starting with git 2.5, you can have both branches checked out at the same time (in different directories). See https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows. Setup via `git worktree add -b gh-pages ../gh-pages origin/gh-pages`.

Bonus: If the content of a subdirectory of your `master` checkout is the content of `gh-pages`, use the script provided at https://github.com/X1011/git-directory-deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```bash
git push origin `git subtree split --prefix build`:$DEPLOY --force
```

You can see working version https://github.com/rofrol/closeyoureyesnow/blob/master/build_and_deploy.sh