# merging github gh-pages into master

Tags: github

I know this isn't advised and there's a reason they're separated. But to my [specific case](http://cauerego.github.com/jsoneditor/) gh-pages only have 1 page (*index.html*), and I want that 1 page to contain basically every file on master so it can be demonstrable. I was even considering using [JSbin](http://jsbin.com) until I stumbled upon [github pages](http://pages.github.com/).

So, is there any way to have just the *master* and still keep `user.github.com/project` pointing to it?

Maybe [using symbolic-ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750520/git-branch-gh-pages/4772329#4772329)?

Comment: But gh-pages can have multiple pages. It depends only what you put there. The index.html is just the default.

Comment: @khmarbaise what? I don't want multiple, I want singleton.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question; your gh-pages branch already has all the files from the master branch. If you're asking how to delete everything except index.html:

```
git clone git@github.com:cauerego/jsoneditor.git
cd jsoneditor
git checkout gh-pages
git rm -rf jsoneditor/ jsunit/ test/
git rm LICENSE README try.html
git commit
```

Comment: When I asked the question my gh-pages didn't have the files. I don't recall if I managed to make symbolic-ref work or if I just copied the files - but I basically want to **not need to** copy them from the master branch.