# How to create GitHub pages from a project's documentation?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a project on GitHub that has a directory containing some automatically generated HTML documentation. I would like to use that documentation within GitHub's project pages facility.

So, I've read the instructions on how to [create the project's gh-pages root branch](http://pages.github.com/#project_pages). This effectively creates an empty branch.

What I'd like help with is mirroring the html files in the `/docs` path from the `master` branch, so they are in the root of the `gh-pages` branch. What is the best way of approaching this?

Comment: See [my related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29616287/946850) and a [writeup](http://krlmlr.github.io/git-subbranch) for an alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git branch: gh-pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750520/git-branch-gh-pages)

Comment: Hey @Martijn Pieters, I'm fine with you deleting my post once the question is closed as a dupe. So far, this one hasn't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering my own question here... have achieved what I wanted with Git submodules.

I basically copied what's [detailed in this sake task](https://github.com/drnic/sake-tasks/blob/master/github/pages/migrate_website.sake), but in summary:

- Moved the `docs` path into a temp folder. Commit changes.
- Created a clean `gh-pages` branch as per the [usual instructions](http://pages.github.com/#project_pages)
- Moved everything from the temp folder into the new `gh-pages` branch. Commit changes.
- Back in the master branch, add the remote `gh-pages` as a submodule in the `docs` folder.
- Commit changes. Voila!

Comment: Do you have to then `cd` into the `docs` folder and commit/push everything separately or is there a way to do so with a single command from the root?

Comment: Do you have to pull each update to `gh-pages` into your submodule with this approach? Does it work well in practice?

Answer (score 1):

Mhm, I ended up writing these two Makefile targets to push my docs. I just do make update-doc and it generally works.

```
TMP_PATH="/tmp/some_path"

## the dir containing HTML docs to push to gh-pages
HTML_DIR="html"

## arbitrary dirs created by the doc build system that should be removed
TRASH=latex

update-doc: doc
        rm -rf ${TMP_PATH} && cp ${HTML_DIR} ${TMP_PATH} -R && rm -rf ${HTML_DIR}
        git fetch
        git checkout gh-pages
        cp ${TMP_PATH}/* . -R
        rm -rf ${TRASH}
        git add .
        git commit -m "Update documentation"
        git push -u origin gh-pages
        rm -rf ${TMP_PATH}
        git checkout master

# command to build documentation; can be customised but
# remember to also change the HTML_DIR and TRASH variables
doc:
        doxygen docs/doxygen.conf

.PHONY: doc update-doc
```

I use `doxygen` but you could change this to whatever other documentation system.

This assumes the `gh-pages` branch exists on the remote and was created as explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/).

Answer (score 0):

create symlinks for those files to that spot. You should be able to commit those too.