# GitHub pages: two websites from two branches within the same repository

Tags: next.js, github-actions, github-pages

I have the following branches in my GitHub repository:

- `main` (nothing in here, only one `README.md` file)
- `branch1` - a NextJS project, which contains a `.github/workflows` folder that can deploy the project to GitHub Pages when run.
- `branch2` - a static html website with different content.

I want `branch1` to be deployed at https://username.github.io/repo-name/ using GitHub Actions, and `branch2` to be deployed at https://username.github.io/repo-name/branch2/ as a static site.

What do I do, and how do I start?

PS: The YAML actions pushes the generated static HTML (from `npm run export`) to an automatically created `gh-pages` branch and deploys using the command `gh-pages -d ./out`. It works perfectly fine.

---

EDIT: I may have an idea, but I'm not sure how to start implementing it. GitHub deploys my site from the `gh-page` branch whenever the `gh-pages -d ./out` command is run. So, maybe I can set "Deploy from branch" as `gh-page` under the page settings of my repository, and then in `branch2`, I can write a custom YAML GitHub Action so that whenever a change to the static HTML is made and pushed, it will copy the whole branch (there are CSS and JS subfolders in the branch too btw) over to a folder called `branch2` in the `gh-page` branch. But that folder would be deleted whenever `branch1` has pushes, due to the command `gh-pages -d ./out` being run. So maybe edit the NextJS deploy script to make it so that it doesn't delete the `branch2` folder when deploying? And also change the static HTML deploy script so that it doesn't copy the entire branch every time there's a change, but only the file/lines that changed. But will this turn out to be too complicated?

---

EDIT2: Here's my workflow script.

```yaml
# Sample workflow for building and deploying a Next.js site to GitHub Pages
#
# To get started with Next.js see: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started
#
name: Deploy Next.js site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["nextjs"]     # This is my "branch1"

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow only one concurrent deployment, skipping runs queued between the run in-progress and latest queued.
# However, do NOT cancel in-progress runs as we want to allow these production deployments to complete.
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Detect package manager
        id: detect-package-manager
        run: |
          if [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/yarn.lock" ]; then
            echo "manager=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "runner=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          elif [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/package.json" ]; then
            echo "manager=npm" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=ci" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "runner=npx --no-install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Unable to determine package manager"
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "16"
          cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
        with:
          # Automatically inject basePath in your Next.js configuration file and disable
          # server side image optimization (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized).
          #
          # You may remove this line if you want to manage the configuration yourself.
          static_site_generator: next
      - name: Restore cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            .next/cache
          # Generate a new cache whenever packages or source files change.
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-${{ hashFiles('**.[jt]s', '**.[jt]sx') }}
          # If source files changed but packages didn't, rebuild from a prior cache.
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }} && cd about-me && npm i && cd ..
      - name: Build with Next.js
        run: cd about-me && ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next build && cd ..
      - name: Static HTML export with Next.js
        run: cd about-me && ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next export && cd ..
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          path: ./about-me/out

  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

The website is currently up and running fine with no problem. Note my branch name on Line 10.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your **specific** question with that?

Comment: I've currently deployed `branch1` with a custom GitHub Actions (NextJS) and it is live at https://username.github.io/repo-name/. `branch2` is currently not deployed, and the `pages` setting in the GitHub repository is currently empty.

Comment: @hakre My question would be, "What should I do to achieve this? Is it even possible to do this in the first place? If so, what would be the best way?"

Comment: Create a .github/workflows directory in the main branch and add two workflow files. Configure the triggers in each workflow file for each branch respectively.

Comment: @DavidNyan10: The procedure is the standard procedure, which is also the reason that it is even possible in the first place. Please find an answer below. /edit: the copy operation you name in your edit is the `git-archive` part in the answer. It basically works as you outline it in your question already. Writing down the workflow file does not seem a problem to you otherwise it has been part of the question, this is merely a conceptual question, right?

Comment: If it's more of a question how to get it done, have the two branch workflows first. while it makes no sense for the final result, you have already each build increment that you can express as YAML Text in your question. Also for the answer the order does not matter, you can start with any of those two. An answer then can better relate to your concrete steps so could better display how an outcome could look like. Reminds me on the [mre]. And please [edit] in all important information into your question, do not hide them in the comments below it.

Comment: Please add the workflow file of `branch1` to your question.

Comment: Wait, sorry I was trying to understand how to implement your answer and was confused on what to do and where to even start first lmao. Yes, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Have your static site with your file and directory layout in the branch `gh-pages` and push it to Github.

Github Pages comes with different site-types but is otherwise relatively straight-forward on how you can do things, therefore let's first review your leading URL layout to then conclude on how your repository branch layout can contribute to the Github Page you have in mind.

By the mapping of the two branches to your URL layout:

1. https://username.github.io/repo-name/
2. https://username.github.io/repo-name/branch2/

you're using the ***project** Github Pages Site-Type* <sup>1</sup> and the

> source files for a project site are stored in the same repository as their project.

> You can publish your site when changes are pushed to a specific branch[.]

The Microsoft Github documentation then starts to become a little bit shy to name that branch, we can only speculate that this is because it is long-time documented in off-site resources like Stackoverflow (e.g. [*"git branch: gh-pages"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750520/367456)), but under **[Troubleshooting publishing from a branch](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#troubleshooting-publishing-from-a-branch)** <sup>2</sup> the branch-name is documented and it is documented how you deploy to it (with `git(1)` (!)):

> Most [...] workflows "deploy" to GitHub Pages by committing the build output to the `gh-pages` branch of the repository, and typically include a `.nojekyll` file. When this happens, the GitHub Actions workflow will detect the state that the branch does not need a build step, and will execute only the steps necessary to deploy the site to GitHub Pages servers.

To conclude from your original URL layout, whenever the NextJS build from `branch1` has finished, you *"checkout"* `branch2` into the `branch2` folder of the NextJS build target directory.

To *"checkout"* `branch2` in a reproducible way use the [`git-archive(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) <sup>3</sup> command as a tarpipe <sup>4</sup>. Not only deals it with file time-stamps but you can also control source and target directory mapping as well as dedicated exclusions (mind that Github Pages are public even if your project repository is private).

Only then you continue to publish that overall result under your Github Pages deployment branch configuration, that is you commit the build target directory as the static documentation directory of the Github Pages branch <sup>5</sup> and push it to the Github remote (`origin` by default, c.f. `git-push(1)`).

---

1. [***Types of GitHub Pages sites***](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites) - https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites
2. [***Troubleshooting publishing from a branch***](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#troubleshooting-publishing-from-a-branch) - https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#troubleshooting-publishing-from-a-branch
3. [***git-archive - Create an archive of files from a named tree***](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive
4. ***tarpipe:*** use `tar | tar` to copy directory trees (here `git archive --format tar | tar`); c.f. [**Tarpipe - Tar (Computing) - Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Tarpipe) and [***Copying Directory Trees with tar and Pipes**, Unix Power Tools Third Edition, by Shelley Powers, Jerry Peek, Tim O'Reilly, Mike Loukides, and other contributors*](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch10_13.htm)
5. *Your Repository* -> **Settings** (last tab) -(> under *"General"*, subsection *"Code and automation"* -)> **Pages** -(> Build and deployment -)> **Branch** the **Select folder** drop-down. - https://github.com/username/repo-name/settings/pages

Comment: So from what I understand:
1. Copy the whole content of `branch2` into the `gh-page` branch without putting it in any dir or anything, just the raw files so that `branch1` looks exactly like `gh-page`. 
2. Deploy my NextJS project branch (`branch1`) by running the workflow action. 
3. Edit the workflow so that it copies `branch2` into `gh-page` every time there's a new commit. 

Is that right? Wouldn't that just make two `index.html` conflict in `gh-page` branch?

Comment: Didn't you wanted to have the contents of the branch "`branch2`" as the subfolder "`branch2`" in your URL-layout and wouldn't that require to copy it into a directory with the same name below the directory that you have configured to publish to Github Pages from within the `gh-pages` branch? This then would not conflict for index.html files as they are in their own directories (it otherwise wouldn't even work technically for a website). [first clarify target locations and source locations, then write the process to handle it that way]

Comment: Ok ok, so here's the plan:
1. Create a workflow in `branch2` that will copy its content to a subfolder called `branch2` in `gh-pages` branch whenever there's a change, like maybe using rsync
`rsync -r --delete --exclude=.git --exclude=node_modules ./ ${{github.workspace}}/../out/branch2/`
Something like that. 
2. Modify the yaml in `branch1` so that it doesn't delete the `branch2` subfolder in `gh-page` branch when it is run after a push. 
3. Go to the GitHub Pages Settings and change the deploy mode to "Branch" and to `gh-page` branch. 

Is that correct? Will that work?

Comment: rsync can't yet operate on git remotes (which could be a fantastic interface idea for git-fast-import) but I guess I'd understand the analogy and yes, that is a subfolder in the `gh-pages` branch. Have you configured to operate in the root folder *or* in a different folder for the web-root in the gh-pages branch (this is in your repository **Pages** setting)? [and yes, it looks to me that this will work]

Comment: _(And please do me a favor: With all the edits your question looks extremely chaotic. That's not good to grasp any longer. Please give it the love it deserves.)_

Comment: Thank you for your help, @hakre! By the way, sorry if I'm asking too much, but how would I make a GitHub action to copy all the files from `branch2` into a new subfolder in `gh-page` that we need to create? I need to create a new YAML file in `branch2` and the workflow code would be run from the `branch2` branch, right?

Comment: in short: fetch the branches, checkout gh-page and archive the branch2 tree to tarpipe it into that folder, then commit any (potential) changes (e.g. allow-empty if you want to commit always). long version: make it a dedicated question isolating that case then I can show this git-archive-tarpipe thing with real command-lines and it is also better to reference. have a _short_ workflow yaml in the question already (e.g. triggered manual and on push for branch2), it must not yet fully work, but to have something to work with.

Comment: I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76035163/github-actions-workflow-to-copy-everything-all-files-and-folders-into-a-folder It'd be great if you could answer, thank you!