# GitHub Actions Workflow Error thinks there's a submodule when there isn't

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

Here's my code:

```yaml
name: Copy files to another branch

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - better-page
    workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
    contents: write
    pages: write
    id-token: write

concurrency:
    group: "pages"
    cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
    copy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout better-page
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
              with:
                  ref: better-page

            - name: Copy files 1
              run: |
                  git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
                  git config --global user.email "action@github.com"
                  git fetch origin better-page:better-page --update-head-ok
                  rsync -r --exclude=.git --exclude=.github --exclude=about-me --exclude=node_modules --exclude=simplified . simplified/
                  git add .
                  git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "create simplified directory"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
                  git push origin better-page # push to remote branch

            - name: Checkout gh-pages
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
              with:
                  ref: gh-pages

            - name: Copy files 2
              run: |
                  git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
                  git config --global user.email "action@github.com"
                  git fetch origin gh-pages:gh-pages --update-head-ok
                  git archive --format tar better-page simplified | tar x -vf -
                  git add .
                  git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "copy files from better-page"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
                  git push origin gh-pages # push to remote branch
```

Basically it copies all content of a branch into a folder, then checkout that folder into another branch.

But it gives me the error during the run of `Checkout gh-pages` right after `Copy files 1`.

```bash
Run actions/checkout@v2
Syncing repository: quincynyan/quincynyan
Getting Git version info
Copying '/home/runner/.gitconfig' to '/home/runner/work/_temp/9f6c9133-fd10-4760-ad2f-75953eb90e34/.gitconfig'
Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/9f6c9133-fd10-4760-ad2f-75953eb90e34' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/quincynyan/quincynyan
/usr/bin/git config --local --get remote.origin.url
https://github.com/quincynyan/quincynyan
Removing previously created refs, to avoid conflicts
Cleaning the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
  /usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
  /usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :"
  Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'simplified' in .gitmodules
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

I didn't even make any references to the "simplified" folder during the checkout, and that branch doesn't even know the folder exists because it hasn't been introduced there yet. What happened? What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Note: I don't have a .gitmodules file.

Comment: Did you check in the repository `.git` folder (or the `.gitconfig` file) if there isn't any `.gitmodules` set?

Comment: Nope, there isn't
```[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
[lfs]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/quincynyan/quincynyan
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "nextjs"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/nextjs
[branch "main"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/main
[branch "gh-pages"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/gh-pages
[branch "better-page"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/better-page
```

Comment: Please always address comments by editing the question, that blob of text is hard to read in a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the same repo, it's trying to checkout the repo a second time, in the same location. Specify a `path` parameter to ensure you have two copies of the repo, one for each branch you want to work in.

Comment: I added the path parameter and now the action runs successfully without any errors. But it did nothing and did not copy any content into the subfolder across the branch. However, it did show a warning ```copy
The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128```

Comment: You need to update your script steps to point to the working directory you cloned into. Instead of there being one repo in your `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` location, you now have two subdirectories, each with a different clone in it.