# How to (ant) build a subfolder from GIT?

Tags: git, jenkins, ant

In a Jenkins freestyle project, how to build an ant project that is in a subfolder?

With SVN, we would just check out the folder with the ant files, but now with GIT, checking out a subfolder of a repo is not supported (as per questions on this site, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)) and I also see no option to CD into a subfolder before the ant task, or a similar option in the "Invoke Ant" step.

Comment: Consider doing a sparse checkout, if you are worried about the space that it takes to checkout a whole commit.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the linked question does show how it works with git (it suggests sparse checkouts, similar to what [eftshift0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0) suggests in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76313856/how-to-ant-build-a-subfolder-from-git#comment134572521_76313856) or [another popular Q&A about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180052/367456)).

But that only as an early commentary, there is an alternative to sparse checkouts working for checking out sub directories from a git repository. It works with `git(1)` pipelining to `tar(1)`. Given we're talking about build systems here, it should be very likely you've got both tools at hand.

The actual `git` command is `git-archive` and this is conceptually a [tarpipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Tarpipe).

You can specify the revision to "checkout", the path you want to "checkout" and where you want to checkout the files to (in this answer, an imaginary `build/ant` target directory):

```
git archive --format tar \
    --prefix build/ant/ \
    HEAD \
    subdirectory/path/to/check-out \
  | tar x -vf -
```

- `git archive`:

  - `--format tar` use tar (tape archiver) format. required.
  - `--prefix build/ant/` the target directory, that is where to checkout to. If not with slash (`/`) at the end, the first component would be prefixed by this only (so not resulting in a directory). If you're checking out into a git repository work-tree, mind that you're checking out into a git repository work-tree. The target directory will be created, incl. all necessary parents.
  - `HEAD` the revision to checkout, replace with the revision you have.
  - `subdirectory/path/to/check-out` the subdirectory you want to checkout from the repository.
- `tar x -vf-`:

  - `x` - extract
  - `-v` - verbose, outputs the files being extracted on standard output
  - `-f-` - file to read, here `-` (minus sign) stands for standard input.
  - **tip:** you can replace `x` with `t` for test, that is showing all file information that would be "checked out", including the final paths.

---

From your question it is not fully clear to me which limitations there are next to not being able to change the working directory. With the `git archive | tar` pipe, you can extract to any directory, including root, however you need to manage what happens then. E.g. when I had this in an answer recently, this was over the top for the user leaving them with a chaotic state in the work-tree of their build-system, they had problems to handle it any longer. YMMV.

---

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76046285/367456